# How to Clean and Prepare an Image

Tags: cloud, cloud-init

Starting with one of the official Ubuntu cloud images, after installing software and making configuration changes, what is the proper next step to clean the image before shutdown so that it is ready to be deployed? The process of running the cloud image and then installing software creates logs in /var/log as well as leaving commands in the shell's history. What is the process needed to refresh the image to a clean state as if it had not yet been booted for the first time?

I see that there is a command `cloud-init clean`, but this appears only to apply to cloud-init's own logs and state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any universal guide for customizing Ubuntu cloud-images. People usually use tools like [Hashicorp Packer](https://www.packer.io/) (or cloud specific services like [Azure VM Image Builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/image-builder-overview), built on top of Packer).

If you want to do this by yourself, `cloud-init clean` is a good start. I also encourage you to have a look at [this documentation for systemd](https://systemd.io/BUILDING_IMAGES/) that goes through more details.

If you mount the disk image (on a loop device for example) you can also use [`chroot`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man8/chroot.8.html) to install packages using `apt` without even booting the image. You can do that with `qemu-nbd` on a vast number of image formats. See (for example) [this gist](https://gist.github.com/shamil/62935d9b456a6f9877b5). This greatly reduces the clean up operations needed. In that case `apt-get clean` should be enough. This method will not work that simply if you are changing anything related to boot and might just not work with some packages which expect the system to be running in their post-install script.